# Is it ok to give reference to paid modules in answers

Tags: discussion

For this [question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/52859/drupal-online-booking-form-builder-for-my-website) an answer was posted which looked like an ad to me. Is it ok to post answers with reference to paid Drupal modules/Code. Should these type of posts be flagged for mod attention ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I thought exactly the same thing....so I deleted the answer and left a comment for the OP to declare any affiliation they may have and to improve the answer in general (it's nothing more than a link answer with some sales text at the moment which we don't want anyway).

Yes, please keep flagging similar answers so we can have a look :)

The section in the [FAQ](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/faq#promotion) spells it out pretty clearly:

> **May I promote products I am affiliated with here?**
>
> The community generally frowns on overt self-promotion and tends to vote it down and flag it as spam, so be careful. Post good, relevant answers, and if they happen to be about your product, so be it. However, you must disclose your affiliation with the product in your answers. Also, if a huge percentage of your posts include a mention of your product, you're clearly here for the wrong reasons. Our advertising rates are quite reasonable; contact our ad sales team for details. We also offer free vote-based advertising for open source projects.

We open-sourcers tend to raise our eyebrows in suspicion at anything that costs money, but there may well be legitimate paid-for solutions out there for Drupal problems (a lot of us would be out of a job if there weren't!). In my opinion we don't want to alienate these *en masse*, but answers alluding to these sorts of solutions definitely need a bit more scrutiny.

Comment: Looks like action was taken before I posted :P